# Boost statechart: How to spread across multiple files?

Tags: c++, boost

First, I manage to implement a state machine in a single header file. I know I need some forward declarations, and I have to define the states from outside to inside. What I really don't understand is: How would I do this with multiple files?

My aproach:

- One header per state
- One header with all possible states, forward declared
- each header which declares a state includes the header which declares its context

Then it looks like this:

```
// forward.h
struct Machine;
struct StA;
struct StB;

// machine.h
#include "forward.h"
struct Machine : sc::state_machine< Machine, StA > {};

// a.h
#include "forward.h" // for StB
#include "machine.h"
struct StA : sc::simple_state< StA, Machine, StB > {};

// b.h
#include "forward.h"
#include "a.h"
struct StB : sc::simple_state< StB, StA > {};
```

Now it's left open how to include the whole thing in the program. My idea was to have one header which includes from outside to inside all the states' headers.

```
// the_machine.h
#include "forward.h"
#include "machine.h"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

// use this header now where you need the state machine
```

However, I don't know if the general idea is ok and even if so, I can't get this to compile (well, not *exactly* this but a machine I built following this design principle).  Having all in one file it pretty easy once you reaized that context needs to be complete, states need to be forward declared and so on, but splitting for complexity and maintenance reasons frays my nerves ... `Incomplete type 'StXY' used in nested name specifier` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Incomplete type` error often appears if you have messed up the order in which headers get included.

- Did you use proper include guards in your header files?
- Sometimes forward declarations get messed up when you have circular includes.
- Sometimes one copies a header to make a similar header (e.g. a.h and b.h) and forgets to change the include guards. This can be very hard to track down.

Try the follwing: create an empty .cpp that just includes `the_machine.h` and only precompile it. There are command line flags for the different compilers that write a file containing the preprocessed translation unit (i.e. one file con0taining all the code the compiler gets to see). Check that file to see if everything is in the order you think it is. Most preprocessors generate `#line` control commands, telling the compiler (and you) what line of what header/source you are looking at.

**Edit:**

If you want to just `#include` machine.h, you will have to include the state definitions *after* the machine definition. That might look odd at a first glance, but this is how it works with templates in general, if you want to split dependant parts. Many people use different file suffixes for the later included parts, because those are no real headers on their own, i.e. you can't include them solely. Example:

```
//Something.h
template <class T>
struct Something
{
   void meow(T const& t);
   int wuff(T const& t, int b);
};

#include "Something.impl" //or .ipp, or other endings...

//Something.impl
template <class T>
void Something<T>::meow(T const& t)
{ /* implement... */ }

template <class T>
int Something<T>::wuff(T const& t, int b)
{ /* implement... */ }
```

Your machine.h would look similar - define the machine and include implementations of the states after it. I would not name states' implementation files `X.h`, because they are no single headers one could just include and use on their own.

Comment: So the basic approach is ok in your eyes? What makes me perplex is that I *need* `Machine`, but *cannot* include it's header `machine.h` directly in my program. Well, I could if I placed all the stuff which is in `the_machine.h` below the `Machine` struct in `machine.h`, but that looks strange since includes usually happen at the beginning of a file.

Comment: The basic approach is good imo, yes. As far as I can see, you *can* include machine.h, but before actually using it (i.e. calling inherited methods of `sc::state_machine`) you have to include definitions for the used states as well. That is typical for templates and the CRTP in particular: you have to include all the definitions before using them. The definitions of the states belong to `Machine`, because it depends on them. For the machine.h part, see my edit to the answer (coming in a few minutes...)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comments and improvements! I will follow your advice with the `impl` files, then it doesn't look *that* odd ;)